# Passing the parameter to the Modal window Antd React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, frontend, antd

I'm trying to create a popup modal window using react and antd, so  when I click on the image it suppose to show the same image in full size.

The problem is that I can't pass the *record.url* inside the Modal window, even though I use the same parameter for the first image and it works fine.

```
render: (text, record) =>
    <div>
      <img id="img1" src={'http://127.0.0.1:8887/' + record.url} onClick={this.handlePreview}/>

      <Modal visible={this.state.previewVisible} onCancel={this.handleCancel}>
          <img src={'http://127.0.0.1:8887/ZmrLMKlc.jpg' } />  // What I need
          <img src={'http://127.0.0.1:8887/' + record.url} />  // My attempt
      </Modal>
    </div>
```

How can I do that or is there a way to declare a variable inside the render method to get the src this way?

```
var = document.getElementById("img1").src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud you do this

```
render: (text, record) =>{
const imgSrc = `http://127.0.0.1:8887/${record.url}`;
return(<div>
  <img id="img1" src={imgSrc} onClick={this.handlePreview}/>

  <Modal visible={this.state.previewVisible} onCancel={this.handleCancel}>
      <img src={imgSrc} />  // What I need
      <img src={'http://127.0.0.1:8887/' + record.url} />  // My attempt
  </Modal>
</div>)
}
```

So what I do is I create a new variable that hold src then pass it to image and also to image in Modal.

Comment: This way is working only for the image again, but not for the Modal.